# GNU Bash 3.2.25(1) Multiple Escape characters brings up directory list

Tags: linux, bash

For example with a Bash terminal window if I type escape escape I get a directory listing. How do I control this or turn it off?

Comment: Try executing `complete -r`.  Does it help?

Comment: No it does not help. The direcoty listing still comes up after a double esc

Comment: I also found out a single tab character does the same thing

Answer (score 0):

This is turned off by the statement `set disable-completion` in `~/.inputrc`. (See section *Readline Variables* in the bash manual.)